# Northwind traders unitprice redundancy?

Tags: database-design, northwind

In the northwind traders database unitprice is listed on both the products and [order details] tables. Both tables list different prices for the same product. Is this a redundancy or is there an explanation for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a reason.

When you change the price of a product, you don't want all orders containing that product changing as well. You need the unitprice in the [Order Details] table to preserve history.

Comment: Correct.  Think of it this way - the "UnitPrice" in the Order Details table is the unit price that the person actually paid - the price that was in effect at the time the order occurred.  It's historical information.